# Responsive tooltip Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button. On click on this button, i want to show a div to the right side of the button, just like tooltip.

This button can be anywhere on the screen. How to show it on the right & make it responsive?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jCvgU/1/)

CSS

```
.tooltip {
    background-color: red;
    background-color:#EDEDED;
    /*background color of tooltip*/
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    z-index:100;
    line-height:1.3em;
    padding:8px;
    width:200px;
    /*default width of tooltip*/
    border-radius:8px;
    /*CSS3 border radius*/
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #888888;
    /*CSS3 shadow*/
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #888888;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #888888;
}
```

Comment: Um. In your demo, it is "shifted downwards". The tip appears under the button. Did you look into using css media selectors?

Comment: I'm on a large screen, and the tooltip is underneath the button, not on the right side

Comment: Wait...i will edit the question...Its all wrong..!

Comment: What do you mean by "Responsive"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reponsive is a little more tricky, but this will position your tooltip to the left of your button (as dynamically as possible for now):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jCvgU/2/)

```
$('#tooltip').click(function () {
    var objButton = $(this);
    var objTooltip = objButton.next();
    var objPosition = objButton.position();
    // Left adds width + padding + offset
    $(".tooltip").css({"top" : objPosition.top, "left" : (objButton.width() + 26) + 'px'}).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer...but when i put some text before button...it doesn't come to perfect right....http://jsfiddle.net/uJ5Q8/

Answer (score 1):

As Alex mentioned, making it responsive will be tricky. But as an alternative, according to the size of the device, you could either place the tool-tip on right or bottom. So to display it on right, you could use as follows:

```css
.tooltip {
   background-color:#EDEDED;
   border:1px solid black;
   border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
   margin-left: 8px;
   padding: 1px 6px;    
   z-index: 999;
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vimalselvam/r3jkf/)

With the above example, even if you add text before the button, the tool tip aligns properly.